# Order by in materialized view doesn't sort the results

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, scylla

I have a table with a structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE kaefko.se_vi_f55dfeebae00d2b3 (
value text PRIMARY KEY,
id text,
popularity bigint);
```

With data that looks like this:

```
value  | id               | popularity
--------+------------------+------------
rally  | 4eff16cb91f96cd6 |          2
reddit | 11aa39686ed66ba5 |          3
red    | 552d7e95af481415 |          1
really | 756bfa499965863c |          1
right  | c5850c6b08f7966b |          1
redis  | 7f1d251f399442d7 |          1
```

And I've created a materialized view that should sort these values by the popularity from the biggest to the smallest ones:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW kaefko.se_vi_f55dfeebae00d2b3_by_popularity AS
SELECT *
FROM kaefko.se_vi_f55dfeebae00d2b3
WHERE popularity IS NOT null
PRIMARY KEY (value, popularity)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (popularity DESC);
```

But the data in the materialized view looks like this:

```
value  | popularity | id
--------+------------+------------------
rally  |          2 | 4eff16cb91f96cd6
reddit |          3 | 11aa39686ed66ba5
really |          1 | 756bfa499965863c
right  |          1 | c5850c6b08f7966b
redis  |          1 | 7f1d251f399442d7
```

---

As you can see there are two main issues:

1. Data is not sorted as defined in the materialized view
2. There is just a part of all data in the materialized view

---

I'm not very experienced in Cassandra and I've already spent hours trying to find the reason why this happens with no avail. Could somebody please help me? Thank you <3

__

I'm using ScyllaDB 4.1.9-0 and cqlsh shows this:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
```

Comment: In Cassandra data is sorted only inside the partition, not globally

Comment: @AlexOtt What does it mean? How can I created an ordered table then?

Comment: this is how Cassandra work - there is no global ordering. If you need global ordering you need to use Spark, or something like... Or another database

Comment: I tried setting up Spark but I honestly didn't succeed. It's too complicated for a frontend guy like me.

Comment: If you need to sort by artitrary column on the whole dataset, then I recommend to look to some other database, or something like Elasticserarch

Comment: @AlexOtt So I ended up using JanusGraph with ScyllaDB and Apache Solr for text search indexing. This is way better "g.V().hasLabel('se_vi_f55dfeebae00d2b3').order().by('popularity', decr)".

Comment: yes, it may work, but you'll need to take into account the limitations of this approach - scalability, potential problems with data sync between scylla and solr, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Alex's comment is 100% correct, the order is within the partition.

```
PRIMARY KEY (value, popularity)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (popularity DESC);
```

This means that the ordering of popularity is descending only for values where the 'value' field is the same - if I was to alter the data you used to show what this would look like as an example, you would get the following:

```
value  | popularity | id
--------+------------+------------------
rally  |          3 | 4eff16cb91f96cd6
rally  |          2 | 11aa39686ed66ba5
really |          3 | 756bfa499965863c
really |          2 | c5850c6b08f7966b
really |          1 | 7f1d251f399442d7
```

The order is on a per partition key basis, not globally ordered.

Comment: I see, so if I wanted to simulate the global ordering then all the rows would have to have the same value. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, although that would then be a very very bad idea - with that single value partition key since all the data will be located on the same node. It is not a suitable solution / work-around

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I cannot have PRIMARY KEY (value, popularity) and two rows with the same value, because primary keys have to be unique.

Comment: I'd recommend this free course from Scylla on data modeling in Scylla/Cassandra. https://university.scylladb.com/courses/data-modeling/

Comment: Correct, the primary key must be primary - and the partition key should equally not be a low cardinality value, thus grouping all the rows with unique primary keys but a single partition key would be a very bad data model for Cassandra.

Comment: @YamiteruXYZ I don't think (like the others mentioning) your datamodel is correct. Your primary key isn't your primary key. You literally have a id column in your datamodel, that column should be part of your primary key (my guess)

Comment: @J.Doe I've already removed the id column, because it wasn't really used anywhere in the logic.

Comment: @Andrew Why is it a very bad data model? What happens under the hood that makes is bad?

Also isn't it kinda dumb that Cassandra cannot create sorted tables and real-time sorting in queries is extremely limited and has a lot of rules and is slow?

Comment: @YamiteruXYZ - cassandra distributes the data based on the partition key - if all of the records have the same partition key, the data would hotspot to the same nodes, e.g. in a 5 node cluster with replication factor 3 - a table which had just 1 partition key value will only hold data on 3 of the 5 nodes.